# Meniscus formed by water is a weighted catenary?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

[image][image]When I modeled the meniscus with a weighted catenary, B cosh(x/A) + C, it perfectly fit the curve of the meniscus. I get why this curve might be a catenary, but why can the meniscus curve be modeled by a weighted catenary curve perfectly, and what is causing the meniscus to have a shape like this?

The first image is a meniscus formed in a 100ml graduated cylinder. The second is formed in a burette.